# Obtaining unformatted p values when using posthoctgh in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm currently analysing a dataset in which the groups are heteroscedastic. I am therefore using a Welch ANOVA to test for significant differences between means. These results are significant, so I therefore wish to perform a post hoc Games-Howell test to determine which groups differ from each other. I am using the posthocTGH function which is part of the userfriendlyscience package. This formats the p-values according to APA standards, but I would like to know what the unformatted values are. I have tried using the formatPvalue = FALSE argument to ammend this, but this does not change the displayed p values.

Code at the moment:

```
posthoc<-posthocTGH(y=dataset$climb.distance, 
           x=dataset$genotype, 
           method=c("games-howell"),
           formatPvalue = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your question, you can get the unformatted p-values as follows:

```
phoc <- posthocTGH(y=ChickWeight$weight, x=ChickWeight$Diet, method="games-howell")
(outmtx <- phoc$output$games.howell)

         diff       ci.lo    ci.hi         t       df            p   p.adjusted
2-1 19.971212   0.3575276 39.58490 2.6378339 201.3839 4.420348e-02 0.1768139320
3-1 40.304545  17.5439718 63.06512 4.5930381 175.9190 4.883308e-05 0.0002929985
4-1 32.617257  13.4519674 51.78255 4.4086175 203.1602 9.873989e-05 0.0004936994
3-2 20.333333  -6.2029177 46.86958 1.9829842 229.9425 1.974058e-01 0.5922172720
4-2 12.646045 -10.9092650 36.20136 1.3891079 235.8785 5.074188e-01 1.0000000000
4-3 -7.687288 -33.8987923 18.52422 0.7590752 226.1567 8.726938e-01 1.0000000000
```

The vector of p-values can be extracted using:

```
outmtx$p.adjusted

[1] 0.1768139320 0.0002929985 0.0004936994 0.5922172720 1.0000000000 1.0000000000
```

I hope this can help you.